# assignment operator for linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class LinkedList
{
private: 

    struct ListNode
    {
    int value;
    struct ListNode *next;
    };

ListNode *head;

public:
    LinkedList()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }
    ~LinkedList();

    const LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList &rhs);

    void appendNode(int);
    void insertNode(int);
    void deleteNode(int);

    ListNode *removeLast();
};

void LinkedList::appendNode(int num)
{
    ListNode *newNode;
    ListNode *nodePtr;

    newNode = new ListNode;
    newNode->value = num;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (!head)
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        nodePtr = head;

        while (nodePtr->next)
        {
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }

        nodePtr->next = newNode;
    }
}

void LinkedList::insertNode(int num)
{
    ListNode *newNode;
    ListNode *nodePtr;
    ListNode *preNode;

    newNode = new ListNode;
    newNode->value = num;

    if (!head)
    {
        head = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        nodePtr = head;
        preNode = NULL;

        while (nodePtr->next)
        {
            preNode = nodePtr;
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }

        if (!preNode) // if new node is to be the 1st in the list
        {
            head = newNode;
            newNode->next = nodePtr;
        }

        else
        {
            preNode->next = newNode;
            newNode->next = nodePtr;
        }

    }
}

void LinkedList::deleteNode(int num)
{
    ListNode *nodePtr;
    ListNode *preNode;

    if (!head)
        return;

    if (head->value == num)
    {
        nodePtr = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = nodePtr;
    }

    else
    {
        nodePtr = head;

        while (nodePtr != NULL && nodePtr->value != num)
        {
            preNode = nodePtr;
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }

        if (nodePtr)
        {
            preNode->next = nodePtr->next;
            delete nodePtr;
        }
    }
}

const LinkedList& LinkedList::operator=(const LinkedList &rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        ListNode *curr, *nextNode;

        curr = head;
        nextNode = NULL;

        while (curr)
        {
            nextNode = curr->next;
            delete curr;
            curr = nextNode;
        }

        ListNode *cptr = new ListNode;
        cptr = rhs.head;
        cptr->next = NULL;

        temp = rhs.head->next;
        while (temp)
            {
                cptr->next = new ListNode;
                cptr->next = temp;
                cptr = cptr->next;
                cptr->next = NULL;

                temp = rhs.head->next;
            }
        }

    return *this;
}

LinkedList::ListNode* LinkedList::removeLast()
{
    ListNode *nodePtr, *preNode;

    if (!head)
    {
        return;
    }

    nodePtr = head;
    preNode = NULL;

    while (nodePtr->next)
    {
        preNode = nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }

    preNode->next = NULL;

    return nodePtr;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    ListNode *nodePtr;
    ListNode *nextNode;

    nodePtr = head;

    while (nodePtr)
    {
        nextNode = nodePtr->next;
        delete nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nextNode;
    }
}
```

Thank you for those who helped me out!

I fixed my assignment operator and my removeLast function.

For removeLast, 2nd last node will point null, then it returns very last node

I am not sure if my assignment operator is fine or not.

as well as removeLast function..

If you guys find the error, then let me know!

thank you again!

Comment: store "tail" node as well, then you don't have to search the whole list to find the last node. (for appendNode)

Comment: Yeah i know tail helps a lot for running time, but, i just want to fully understand SLL first. Thank you for tip doe!

Comment: in insertMode you forgrt to allocate memory to newNode, do it newNode = new ListNode; and you can create a default constructor for ListNode in which you can assing next to NULL so that whenever new node created its next is NULL.

Comment: Another trick is to make a "dummy" node for head when the list is created. You don't count it as a real node. Then you never need to do the "is head null" check. If statements are costly in terms of performance, and the reduced code from not checking makes up for the extra space of the head node.

Comment: In destuctor you are deleting all the node make seprate private function for that like(deleteAll) and call it from the destructor and assignment overload.

Comment: also checking "is head null" is the wrong approach. the compiler assumes that the "true" branch of an if-statement is the default, and preloads instructions on that branch ready for processing. if the if-statement is false, it flushes the instruction cache and loads the other branch. so checking "head == null" causes the program to be optimized only for empty lists, which is a rare case. You want to check "if head is NOT null" as your main branch, and put the "head == null" code in the "else" part.

Comment: @jason lang oh i see, ill code in that way next time

Comment: @user1438832 dont i have to delete all in destructor?

Comment: @GothLoli I think user1438832 was saying that if you put the destructor code into a function, you can also use that at other times. The code itself is fine. e.g. you could make a "ClearList" function that also calls the same code.

Comment: @JasonLang Now i get it. thats a smart idea

Comment: @GothLoli The way this should be done is to forget about the assignment operator for now, and instead write 1) the copy constructor, and then 2) the destructor.  With those two functions alone, the assignment operator for your linked list class would be written with just 3 lines of code without any usage of pointers and without the flaw no one pointed out yet.  The flaw in your code, and even in the answer given, is that you are removing nodes before calling `new`.  What if `new` throws an exception?  How are you going to recover those nodes you deleted?  Your object now becomes corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, can you guys teach me how to declare "ListNode *removeLast();"?

```
LinkedList::ListNode* LinkedList::removeLast()
```

You just had the return type and class crossed over, but ListNode is also declared inside LinkedList, so you have to specify it as "LinkedList::ListNode" whenever you use it.

As far as I can tell, your destructor looks find. You're just setting one pointer equal to another pointer, that doesn't trigger the copy constructor.

As for creating a deep copy, pointers just hold memory addresses, they aren't the thing themselves.

```
ListNode *node = head;
```

Just creates a pointer referring to the head node. To make a copy, you have to do something like this:

```
ListNode node = *head; // sometimes brackets such as (*head) avoids errors
```

or this

```
ListNode *node = new ListNode;
*node = *head;
```

.

```
*
```

before a pointer's name is "de-referencing". It is a reference to the object pointed at instead of the pointer variable. You can then use the normal copy semantics. For very simple classes (i.e. all simple objects), the default copy behavior is sufficient.